# Laravel выборка моделей с сортировкой по relation моделям?

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, laravel, orm

Хочу отсортировать текущие  посты по именам автора и популярности категории.
Сейчас у меня что-то в таком духе:

```
$posts= Post::with(['author' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('name', 'desc');
        }, 'category' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('popularity', 'desc');
        }])->get();
```

Вернет 1, 5, 11. Стандартная выборка ASC по дате создания.
А должно, к примеру, 11, 1, 5. Пост с id 11 находится в в популярной категории и имя его автора начинается с "А".

**Как сделать сортировку  в данном случае, скажите пожалуйста?**

p.s. без джойнов и деление  на мелкие подзапросы, одним запросом через ORM.